# Use bootstrap but ignore their containers (classes)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For a project, I have to use a Modal (pop up) which I prefer to use Bootstrap for.

However the project (which was original built with their own custom code so no bootstrap), when I do add the bootstrap links (into the head the script, and css links etc) into it, it now changes the my own `.container` classes to Bootstrap their values...

How can I ignore those?

Comment: I’d just cut out tehe modal css from bootstrap to build your own for your website. You will hit many issue with this approach

Comment: I would either make the .container class you have more specific so that it uses that class over the bootstrap class or rename your container classes to something else so that it isn't using a .container class to remove the clash. Either way - both are messy!

Answer (score -1):

Go here

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

Remove everything except modal

then click Compile and Download

It's bootstrap 3.4 but I don't think modal component went through a lot of changes.